# What devices currently support Apple ARKit while its in preview mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, arkit, iphone7plus

I'm trying to play around with Apple's new [ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/arkit/) and have downloaded their sample `ARKitExample` project into Xcode 9 (beta).

Since ARKit doesn't work in the Apple simulator, I'm trying to archive, export and install this `ARKitExample` app onto my iPhone 7+ so I can actually take ARKit for a test spin as an actual user.

However from that example project's own README:

> "*ARKit and this sample app require iOS 11 and a device with an A9 (or later) processor. (ARKit is not available in iOS Simulator.)*"

Looking at the [specs for iPhone 7+](http://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_7_plus-8065.php), it looks like I cannot upgrade my phone to iOS 11, **which makes me think that I cannot deploy and run this `ARKitExample` app on my phone.**

However I see lots of confusing articles about which devices currently support ARKit, [like this one](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2017/06/list-iphone-ipad-compatible-arkit-ios-11.html), which seems to indicate that my phone **does** support it.

So I ask: do I need to figure out how to upgrade my iPhone 7+ to iOS11, or will everything work fine as-is, or do I need to find some other device that *does* run iOS 11? If that last scenario is the case: what devices currently run iOS 11?! I don't think it's even been released yet as it still stands in [preview mode](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-11-preview/)...

Comment: You need an iPhone 6S or later, with iOS 11 beta installed.

Comment: Thanks @nathan, so you're saying that **it is possible** for me to upgrade my iPhone 7+ to use an iOS 11 beta version?!

Comment: Yes, you need to enroll in the iOS developer program or Apple Beta Software Program to run the iOS 11 beta before it is officially released.

Comment: Thanks @nathan (+1 again) - last question: are there any **free** options there? I know a typical Apple Developer license is like $99 USD/year, but I'm not some big fancy software shop, I'm just a dude looking to play around with ARKit ;-)

Comment: It's free, read more here: https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/

Comment: You can run your own apps on your own personal device free of charge. You only need to upgrade to a paid account when you want to publish your apps to the App Store (or use other apple services like TestFlight). Take a look at this page: https://developer.apple.com/programs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**List of iPhone and iPad Compatible with ARKit in iOS 11**:

- iPhone SE
- iPhone 6s
- iPhone 6s Plus
- iPhone 7
- iPhone 7 Plus
- iPad Pro (All three variants and models)
- New 9.7-inch iPad (2017)

Comment: Right....but my iPhone 7+ is currently on iOS 10, and according to their own docs, I need iOS 11, but iOS 11 isn't available yet...see my conundrum?!

Comment: @smeeb iOS 11 is available for Developers and beta testers.

Comment: Thanks @V.Khambir (+1) - can I get iOS 11 on my iPhone or does it need to be an iPad or some other device?

Comment: @smeeb, iOS 11 Compatible Devices List: http://osxdaily.com/2017/06/06/ios-11-compatible-devices-list/